# Sitecore: Full text search using lucene

Tags: lucene, sitecore

I'm using sitecore 8 and I'm looking for a way to run a full text search for all my sitecore content. I have a solution in place, but I feel there's got to be a better way to do this.

My approach:
i have a computed field that merges all text fields into a single computed field. Before I execute a search I tokenize my search text and build a ORed predicate to match on the field.

I do not like this approach because it gets really complicated if I need to boost items that match the title vs the body i.e. i loose the field level boosting.

FYI: my code is very similar to this [so post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17257392/how-to-perform-search-for-multiple-terms-in-sitecore-7-contentsearch-api#17580876).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sitecore already maintains a full text field, `_content`, that contains all the text fields. You can run your search against that. You can even create computed fields that add to `_content` (such as the datasource content example [here](http://www.techphoria414.com/Blog/2013/November/Sitecore-7-Computed-Fields-All-Templates-and-Datasource-Content)).

So assuming you are building a LINQ query for your full text search, and have already filtered on templates, latest version, location, etc., adding your search terms to the query would look something like this:

```cs
var terms = SearchTerm.Split();
var currentExpression = PredicateBuilder.True<SiteSearchResultItem>();
foreach (var term in terms)
{
    //Content is mapped to _content
    currentExpression = PredicateBuilder.And(currentExpression, x => x.Content.Contains(term));
}
query = query.Where(currentExpression);
```

Typically you would want to AND search terms rather than ORing them.

You are right that field level boosting is lost in this. In the end, Lucene is not a great solution for creating a quality full-text site search. If this is an important requirement, you may want to look at Coveo or even something like a Google Site Search.